# How to set height, width and position of panel of bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to set height, width and position of panel of bootstrap?

Here is my code

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <div class="panel-heading">Welcome User!</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        panel body ....
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">panel footer</div>
</div>
```

And how to set the panel to upper right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.panel.panel-default{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you have typo in panel-default

you can use

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <div class="panel-heading">Welcome User!</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          panel body ....
      </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">panel footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That will make your panel in the top right corner